# Are there missing solutions in this linear system of higher order differential equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I am aware that second order derivatives must always have two solutions. However, I am currently trying to do a lab report for a coupled pendulums experiment in which we find the following linear system of second order differential equations (describing the position as a function of time of the two masses): $$\dfrac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-\omega_0^2-k & & k\\k & & -\omega_0^2-k\\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\end{pmatrix}$$

And the lab notes states that all solutions are linear combinations of the following two solutions $$\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\end{pmatrix} = A_{sym}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\\end{pmatrix}\cos{(\omega_{sym}t+\phi_{sym})}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\end{pmatrix} = A_{asym}\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\\end{pmatrix}\cos{(\omega_{asym}t+\phi_{asym})}$$

where $\omega_{sym} = \omega_0$ and $\omega_{asym} = \sqrt{\omega_0^2+2k}\\$

I am confused because there are two second order differential equations in the system which I believe should both have two solutions each meaning that there should be four independent vector solutions (as combinations of the two solutions of $x_1$ and $x_2$). I suppose that the reason is because when the $\pm$ square roots of the eigenvalues end up as the same solution after expanding out the complex exponential since $\cos(x) = \cos(-x)$ but it is quite unclear to me if this is the real reason. My question is how do we know there are no missing solutions and that the whole solution space is spanned by the symmetric and antisymmetric solutions above.

Comment: Hint: $\phi_{\text{sym}}$ and $\phi_{\text{asym}}$ are undetermined.

Comment: I am aware of the arbitrary constants (with the amplitude and phase arising from a complex scalar). Could you please elaborate why these constants are the reason for the lack of an extra two independent solutions?

Comment: Set them to $0$ and $\frac\pi2$ and you get 2 independent solutions. See "polar coordinates", they also span the plane without being linear coefficients.

Comment: Could somebody please provide a simple thorough answer as to why the two solutions span all solutions?